# Strange results using PHP while loop running over mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a set of database results where some of the columns have empty fields. I'm running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE category = '$category' ORDER BY name
```

The PHP that's outputting the results is this (much simplified version):

```
while ($qValues = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($qValues["licence"] != "") {
        $lice = 'Licence: ' . $qValues["licence"];
    }
    if ($qValues["publisher"] != "") {
       $pub = 'Publisher: ' . $qValues["publisher"];
    }
}
```

What's happening is, if the previous row had a publisher, but the current row has no publisher (not null, empty string) it is outputting the previous row's data.

I've no idea how this is happening because in my mind, `mysql_fetch_array` has the data in a grid, and the while loop advances it's internal counter one row after another. I don't understand how one row's data could bleed over into the next row if that row contained an empty string.

What's happening here?

Comment: @i_Conica What if I want to see all data in the "Food N' Things" category?

Comment: Mike B, I don't understand your question? My problem is that the new iteration of the loop is only overwriting the previous loop's data if it contains a new string, if it contains an empty string, it's still storing the previous iteration (database row)'s data.

Comment: @i-CONICA, you'd want to escape the category if it has a single quote.

Comment: Hi, Marcus. I know the reason for escaping variables, I just don't know why Polynomial presumed I must be getting $category from the user side, and that I mustn't be escaping it, none of that information is present in my question or code. I appreciate his offering of advice, though.

Comment: @i-CONICA The source of the params used in queries has no bearing over whether or not they should be escaped. It's not a security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only setting the variables if the columns have values, the variables don't get reset when the columns are blank. This causes the issue where you're seeing the values from the previous record.

You should set the variables every time, even if the column is blank. You can use `else` statements:

```
while ($qValues = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($qValues["licence"] != "") {
    $lice = 'Licence: ' . $qValues["licence"];
} else {
    // Set to blank so as not to keep value from last iteration
    $lice = "";
}
if ($qValues["publisher"] != "") {
    $pub = 'Publisher: ' . $qValues["publisher"];
} else {
    // Set to blank so as not to keep value from last iteration
    $pub = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset `$pub` to `$pub = ""` each time through the loop...

```
while ($qValues = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $lice = "";
    $pub = "";

    if ($qValues["licence"] != "") {
        $lice = 'Licence: ' . $qValues["licence"];
    }
    if ($qValues["publisher"] != "") {
        $pub = 'Publisher: ' . $qValues["publisher"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a better solution then if/else. Initializing variables is a good practice that should be followed.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't resetting the variables in each iteration, so you see the old values. To fix it you could do for example do this:

```
if ($qValues["licence"] != "") {
    $lice = 'Licence: ' . $qValues["licence"];
} else {
    $lice = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the value of publisher and licence to a php variable. if the mysql result contains an empty string it will still keep the content of the previous row
unset the 2 variables each time you loop through the result:

```
while ($qValues = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$lice = $pub = "";
if ($qValues["licence"] != "") {
    $lice = 'Licence: ' . $qValues["licence"];
}
if ($qValues["publisher"] != "") {
   $pub = 'Publisher: ' . $qValues["publisher"];
}
}
```